# NTP synchronization

Tags: sync, ntp

I am using chrony as the NTP.
Timedatectl shows that my NTP is not synchronized.

With "chronyc tracking", it shows not synchronized.

With "chronyc sources -v", it shows the sources not reachable.

With "ping the source ip", it is able to ping.

By checking if the port listening to chrony, the port is open.

There is no firewall enabled.

Is there any other possible way to troubleshoot and diagnose the problem I faced?

Thanks

Comment: can you update your question with `timedatectl status` output?

Comment: Have you run this command `timedatectl set-ntp true`?

Comment: Post the exact commands you used, along with their output.  Use https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/ if you'd prefer not to clutter your post with them.

Answer (score 0):

If your sources aren't reachable, you can't synchronize.  It's that simple.

Are the sources under your control?  If not, there could be a firewall or a router dropping traffic somewhere between you and your sources.

A better way to troubleshoot NTP connectivity than `ping` is to use `ntpdate -dv NTP_SERVER_IP`.  Post the output of that along with your other diagnostics and we can narrow down the problem.